# How to pass Async data return from an Observable from Child to Parent component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, viewchild, asyncdata

I am trying to pass Async data from child to parent component. But in here `console.log(this.values)` inside  `ngAfterViewInit()` gives an empty value in parent component html page load.  But if i click apply button in child component it will emit the event an `console.log(this.values);` inside `getValues($event)` method prints.

This is my parent component .ts file

```
name = 'ViewUI';
@ViewChild('ChildValues', { static: false }) childReference: ChildComponent;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.values = this.childReference.this.responseValues;
  console.log(this.values);
  mapResponse(this.values);
}

In here `mapResponse(this.values)` method runs before coming data from `this.values` from child component to parent.
getValues($event) {
  this.values = $event;
  console.log(this.values);
  this.apply();
}
```

This is my parent component .html file

```
<app-child #ChildValues (getEvent)=" getValues($event)" [name]="name"></app-child>
```

This is my child component .html file.

```
<button (click)="applyResponses()" mat-raised-button>
  Apply
</button>
```

This is my Child component .ts file

```
  export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
      responseValues = {
            names: [], ages: []
        };
      @Output() getEvent = new EventEmitter < any > ();
      @Input() name: string;
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.getNames();
        this.getAges();
        console.log(this.name);
      }
    
     getNames() {
       this.apiService.getnames(Id).subscribe((names) => {
         this.responseValues.names = [names[0].name];
        });
     }
    
     getAges() {
       this.apiService.getages(Id).subscribe((ages) => {
         this.responseValues.ages = [ages[0].age];
        });
     }
      applyResponses() {
        this.getEvent.emit(this.responseValues);
        console.log(this.responseValues);
      }
    }
```

How can i get data from child to parent component on parent page load?

Comment: Why do you want to pass data from a child to a parent component? Why not the other way round? It would simplify your use case.

Comment: Yea i have parent components and  have a child component to drop downs bar

Answer (score 1):

why not, in ngOnInit in child, you define a new emiter?

```
@Output()dataReceived= new EventEmitter < any > ();

ngOnInit()
{
   forkJoin(this.getNames(),this.getAges()).subscribe(([names,ages]:[any[],any[]])=>{
       this.dataReceived.emit({names:names,ages:ages})
   })
}
```

And in your parent?

```
<app-child (dataReceived)="storeData($event)"></app-child>
storeData(data:any)
{
    console.log(data.names,data.ages)
}
```

**Update** it's an answer about a question in comment, Remember that you are not sure that you get the data. To check it we are going to "simulate" a slow response from server. for this import delay from 'rxjs/operators'

```
import {delay} from 'rxjs/operators'
```

And change the subscripcion by

```
this.apiService.getages(Id).pipe(
  delay(10000))
  .subscribe((ages) => {
     this.responseValues.ages = [ages[0].age];
    });
```

If you click the button before 10 seconds you has not the data

Comment: But still if i check the  `console.log(this.values);` inside `ngAfterViewInit() ` it shows an empty object

Comment: Mandara, you can not know when the data is ready -you are working with async calls- so you need "make something" **inside subscribe function** (imagine that you call spend 10 seconds and you click the button before this 10 seconds -you has not value too-),

Comment: Actually if click apply button data is coming.But i want to get data on the initial page load of the parent component html `(click)="applyResponses()`

Comment: i want to run another function like `mapResponse()` and i want to send those `this.values` to another `mapResponse()` method.But  this method `mapResponse()` calls before `this.values` come from child component

Comment: Mandara, if you click apply button data is comming because your call is finished (typically a call can spend 1 or 2 second maximum), but you don't know when your data is ready. Your'e **sure** that inside subscribe function you get the data but no more. (I updated the answer to "simulate a delay)

Comment: adding a delay was a useful thing `delay(10000)`. Other than that  is there any useful efficient solution

Comment: NO, I want to say that you need put the code in subscribe, It's only an e.g. NOT use delay, the answer is NOT use delay, it's understand the observables are async

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223336/discussion-between-mandara-and-eliseo).